# Uncaught TypeError: $newElems.imagesLoaded is not a function Error masony.pkgd.js

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I had an error below script.

devtools shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: $newElems.imagesLoaded is not a function

There is something wrong with: `$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){`...

How can I fix it?

```js
$(function(){
    var $container = $('.infinite-container');

    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "#infinite_pagination",
        nextSelector : "#infinite_pagination .next",
        itemSelector : ".infinite-container .follow-item",
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'END',
            img: './img/loading.gif'
        }
    },

    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/infinite-scroll/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you load a script file that contains that method?